# Event Listing Wordpress Plugin

Tags: wordpress, events, plugins

I'm seeking a very specific event plugin for wordpress (if it exists), if you can suggest one please let me know! Or if there's another easy workaround, I'd appreciate it!

Basically I want to list my events as 4 column square images at the top of a page under the UPCOMING EVENTS section - just like this screenshot:
[Screenshot 1 - Upcoming Events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EipCk.jpg)

But after the event passes I'd like it to drop down to the PAST EVENTS section (automatically if possible) - if manually, I'd like the images to stack so if there's an odd number of past events the most recent would be at the top and the single event would be at the bottom. The only workaround I've found is for the single event to be at the top and I keep adding rows to the top of the PAST EVENTS section. See the next screenshot for clarification. Thanks so much for taking a look!

[Screenshot 2- Past Events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fniB.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Events Manger does this, you would obviously have to use styling in order to make it appear across the top but their easy widget implementation allows you to select how many events display. You then just need to style the widget.

You can also then enable in the settings archive events, once enabled you will be able to display past events.

If you purchase the pro version you can also take payment for tickets online if you so wish.

https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/events-manager/

This website isn't mean't to be used for looking for recommendations due to certain reasons of favouritism and much more. However, I did need a similar plugin to what you require and this was the one I used. It should fit your needs.